# Show arguments that matched in result

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching

I have a POSTGRESQL DB that I am querying. I am looking at a specific field for a list of values. The query is functional but I would like to display what entry in the list of values was matched against to make that entry valid for the query.

```
SELECT to_timestamp(posts.createat/1000), posts.message, users.username, channels.displayname, channels.name, channels.type 
FROM posts
INNER JOIN users 
    ON posts.userid = users.id 
INNER JOIN channels 
    ON posts.channelid = channels.id 
WHERE 
    posts.message ILIKE ANY (VALUES ('%testValue1%'),('%testValue2%'),('%testValue3%'),('%testValue4%'))
```

I would like to know which of the 'testValues' was found in the message field.

Comment: Please remember to always declare your version of Postgres. (`SELECT version()` helps)

Comment: My bad... it's 9.6.8...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your use case guarantees that only one pattern can match at a time or you are only interested in the **first match**, add a simple `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(p.createat/1000), p.message, u.username, c.displayname, c.name, c.type 
     , CASE 
         WHEN p.message ILIKE '%testValue1%' THEN '%testValue1%'
         WHEN p.message ILIKE '%testValue2%' THEN '%testValue2%'
         WHEN p.message ILIKE '%testValue3%' THEN '%testValue3%'
         WHEN p.message ILIKE '%testValue4%' THEN '%testValue4%'
       END AS first_match
FROM   posts     p
JOIN   users     u ON p.userid = u.id 
JOIN   channels  c ON p.channelid = c.id 
WHERE  p.message ILIKE ANY (VALUES ('%testValue1%'),('%testValue2%'),('%testValue3%'),('%testValue4%'));
```

One way to get **all matches**:

```
ARRAY [CASE WHEN p.message ILIKE '%testValue1%' THEN '%testValue1%' END
     , CASE WHEN p.message ILIKE '%testValue2%' THEN '%testValue2%' END
     , CASE WHEN p.message ILIKE '%testValue3%' THEN '%testValue3%' END
     , CASE WHEN p.message ILIKE '%testValue4%' THEN '%testValue4%' END] AS all_matches
```

Comment: This is it. Thanks!
I went with the ARRAY set, as to know what matches to look for.
I'm new to POSTGRESQL - so this was super helpful.
..edit..
I tried upvoting... I'm a newb so it not reflecting that.